# How to read main cookie from the sub domain with an existing sub domain cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

I need to use main domain cookies for my sub domains as with higher priority when both sub and main domain cookies exists.

The problem is when I'm on **sub.domain.com** and there exist cookies for

- sub.domain.com
- .domain.com

The PHP global `$_COOKIE` contains `$_COOKIE['data'] == 'sub.domain.com'`.
I would like to check if there is also a **.domain.com** cookie and use it.

How do I read the main cookie when I'm on a sub domain with an existing sub domain cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `$_SERVER ['HTTP_COOKIE']` variable that contains both sub domain and main domain cookie variables with the same name as one large string. In the following simple piece of code the `$cookie_variable` array will contain both values of specific variables:

```
if( 'sub.domain.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  $var_name = 'somedata';
  $domains_counter = 0;
  foreach(explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']) as $cookie_variable_string) {
    if( false !== strpos($cookie_variable_string, $var_name.'=') ) {
      $cookie_variable[$domains_counter] = urldecode(
          trim(
              substr(
                  $cookie_variable_string, 
                  strpos($cookie_variable_string, $var_name) + strlen($var_name.'=')
              )
          )
      );
      $domains_counter++;
    }
  }
  var_dump($cookie_variable);
}
```

Here's a function that gets all variables:

```
public static function get_http_cookie_variables() {
  $domains_counter = [];
  foreach(explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']) as $cookie_variable_string) {
    $key_value = explode('=', $cookie_variable_string);
    $cookie_var_name = trim($key_value[0]);
    if(is_null($domains_counter[$cookie_var_name])) {
      $domains_counter[$cookie_var_name] = 0;
    }
    $http_cookie_variables[$cookie_var_name][$domains_counter[$cookie_var_name]] = urldecode(trim($key_value[1]));
    $domains_counter[$cookie_var_name]++;
  }

  return $http_cookie_variables;
}
```

Comment: get_http_cookie_variables() function fails because $domains_counter is not initialized. I simply removed it alltogether since I am not interested in that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the gist of your issue is reading a cookie set in domain.com from sub.domain.com.

Add

`session.cookie_domain = .domain.com`

to your `php.ini` to make this happen. If you're on a shared hosting enviroment and can't modify your ini file, try having this somewhere in your code:

`ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");`

You should now be able to access cookies set by domain.com on subdomain.domain.com.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this is too global change that I prefer to avoid if possible, because it makes session global for all sub domains. I want sessions to be separated for sub domains. I need only to read part of cookie of main domain. I'm already able to access main domain cookie, but only if there is no sub domain cookie, that for some reason preferred by server. Is there way to read both cookies at same time?

Comment: Using the `ini_set()` method should ensure that the configuration changes should only affect your site for the duration of the request (if you're worried the changes will affect other sites that run on your server).

Comment: Jahufar thank you very much! I'm very appreciate your involvement.

Comment: This worked a treat in my situation where on the first load, the cookie from my subdomain was not reading the main domain's COOKIE. Sometimes not even the second load, but always on the third. This seems to have fixed the issue.