# PHP $_SESSION variables differ when www is in URL

Tags: php, session, variables, dns, host

I'm just having some issues with my PHP script which is meant to take the user's UID from the session superglobal, but it wasn't working, saying that $_SESSION['uid'] wasn't set.  After fiddling around, I found that adding "www." to the URL brought back the session variables.  Is there a way to unify sessions regardless of the host portion of the URL?  It seems like a lot of extra work to ensure that users remain on either "www.example.com" or "example.com".  Or maybe this isn't the issue and there's something else I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be forcing redirects to either www or non-www on your server.  But I think this is the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669428/how-to-read-main-cookie-from-the-sub-domain-with-an-existing-sub-domain-cookie-i

Comment: What's the value of `session.cookie_domain` ini setting?

Comment: @Jack session.cookie_domain is blank in my ini

Comment: @danronmoon that might just be it, I'll let you know!

Comment: Then what is likely to have happened is that the cookie was set based on the domain at that time; forcing that value to `.domain.com` should make the whole thing work.

Comment: @Jack Thank you, everything works perfectly now!