# How to read cookie from subdomain in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

Can anyone tell me how to read cookie from subdomain. I can set the cookie for subdomain but unable to read it.

Please tell me what is the syntax in PHP to read cookie from subdomain.

Comment: See [stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669428/how-to-read-main-cookie-from-the-sub-domain-with-an-existing-sub-domain-cookie-i

Hope this helps you

Comment: Try this [stack overflow][1]
website

i hope this helps you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: Try this [stack overflow][1]
website

I hope this helps

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Answer (score 1):

If you're enabled to read in other subdomain, it's probably because you didn't properly set the cookie to begin with.

`$date_of_expiry=time()+ 3600;
setcookie( "cookie_name", "cookie_value", $date_of_expiry, "/", "example.com" );`

It's important that you put the last argument for the cookie to be available in other subdomains.

Also, the cookies must be set before page output.

Comment: Yeah @Ola you are right but the cookie is not set by me. My client has set the cookie and I have to access it like that only.